# Feeding multiple video streams to one ML model using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: opencv, video, camera, stream, multiprocessing

Currently I have a system of ML models that run in their own processes in Python. It works perfectly when a single video camera feed is input but now I need to feed video from multiple sources and only have resources to run one instance of the model. I tried to batch process multiple video streams but it is not really scalable for more than 5 cameras. Is there any Python framework or pipeline that could be helpful? Please suggest.